# What should be the correct sequence of statements when catch block is not given?

Tags: java, exception

I have following code snippet :-

```
public class MyProgram { 
    public static void throwit(){  
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        try {
            System.out.println("Hello world ");
            throwit();
            System.out.println("Done with try block ");
        }
        finally {
            System.out.println("Finally executing ");
        }
    }
}
```

As far I know, 
Once the program throws a RuntimeException (in the throwit() method) that is not caught, the finally block will be executed and the program will be terminated. If a method does not handle an exception, the finally block is executed before the exception is propagated.

But, the output I get have different order each time 
the ouptuts I got :

OUTPUT 1:-

```
        Hello world 
        Finally executing 
        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException 
            at tutorialspoint.A.throwit(A.java:6) 
            at tutorialspoint.A.main(A.java:13)
```

OUTPUT 2:-

```
        Hello world 
        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException 
            at tutorialspoint.A.throwit(A.java:6) 
            at tutorialspoint.A.main(A.java:13) 
        Finally executing
```

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding is correct. First the finally block is executed and then the exception is propagated.

The 2nd output is probably due to the fact that your program's output is written to `System.out` and the execption's details are written to `System.err`. Since both streams are re-directed to the same window, the order in which they are printed can change in different executions.

If you add the line `System.setErr(System.out);` to the start of your `main` method, all the output (including the errors) will be written to `System.out`, and you'll always see the order as in your OUTPUT 1.

Answer (score 0):

## You are corrrect.

Output may be due to racing conditions in `System.out` which outputs to Standard console and `System.err` which outputs to error console.